# Using python to read txt files and answer questions

Tags: python

```
a01:01-24-2011:s1 
a03:01-24-2011:s2 
a02:01-24-2011:s2 
a03:02-02-2011:s2 
a03:03-02-2011:s1 
a02:04-19-2011:s2 
a01:05-14-2011:s2 
a02:06-11-2011:s2 
a03:07-12-2011:s1 
a01:08-19-2011:s1 
a03:09-19-2011:s1 
a03:10-19-2011:s2 
a03:11-19-2011:s1 
a03:12-19-2011:s2
```

So I have this list of data as a txt file, `where animal name : date : location`
So I have to read this txt file to answer questions.

So so far I have

```
text_file=open("animal data.txt", "r") #open the text file and reads it.
```

I know how to read one line, but here since there are multiple lines im not sure how i can read every line in the txt.

Comment: good question, line by line file readings act kind of weird

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop.

```
text_file = open("animal data.txt","r")
for line in text_file:
    line = line.split(":")
    #Code for what you want to do with each element in the line
text_file.close()
```

Comment: `line` will contain a list: `['a03','12-19-2011','s2']`

Comment: Putting it into a list allows for each element to be easily accessed.

Comment: so if that was the case how would i be able to interpet the data to answer question

Comment: You can use indexing (i.e. `line[0]` to access the first item in the list, which is the animal name)

Comment: If you don't want a list just omit the line.split() bit. There aren't many instances when you would want to do that though.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the format of this file, you can shorten it even more over the other answers:

```
with open('animal data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        animal_name, date, location = line.strip().split(':')
        # You now have three variables (animal_name, date, and location)
        # This loop will happen once for each line of the file
        # For example, the first time through will have data like:
        #     animal_name == 'a01'
        #     date == '01-24-2011'
        #     location == 's1'
```

Or, if you want to keep a database of the information you get from the file to answer your questions, you can do something like this:

```
animal_names, dates, locations = [], [], []

with open('animal data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        animal_name, date, location = line.strip().split(':')
        animal_names.append(animal_name)
        dates.append(date)
        locations.append(location)

# Here, you have access to the three lists of data from the file
# For example:
#     animal_names[0] == 'a01'
#     dates[0] == '01-24-2011'
#     locations[0] == 's1'
```

Comment: sort of moving on to a new topic, how to process the data output, but good nevertheless

Comment: I thought I'd try to be helpful, since the OP asked about interpreting the data in a comment on @AHuman's answer.

Comment: still on the note of opening text, it is still not working and the following shows up builtins.FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'animal data.txt' even though im pretty sure that file already exsists.

Comment: Are you running the script from within the same directory as the 'animal data.txt' file? If not, you have to specify the full path to the file, or use the ``os`` module to change directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `with` statement to open the file, in case of the `open` was failed.

```
>>> with open('data.txt', 'r') as f_in:
>>>     for line in f_in:
>>>         line = line.strip() # remove all whitespaces at start and end
>>>         field = line.split(':')
>>>         # field[0] = animal name
>>>         # field[1] = date
>>>         # field[2] = location
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the closing the file. You better use the `with` statement to ensure the file gets closed.

```
with open("animal data.txt","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.split(":")
        # Code for what you want to do with each element in the line
```

Comment: you basically said the exact same thing as the answer above, and that one only made a minor modification to the first one

Comment: When you look at the history of the answer above, there was initially no close operation on the file. So why a -1 if it was more correct?